# Changing opacity of each shape seperately in an array p5.js

Tags: arrays, transparency, p5.js

I'm new to coding. I created a simple code and I need help with targeting each of the elements (each rectangle) in the array seperately. My goal is to change the opacity or transparency of each of the rectangles.

I can simply do `fill(0, 255, 100, 50)`and add an alpha value but this changes all of the rectangles..
I want to change the transparency - Alpha values: 50, 100, 150, 200, 250 respectively for each rectangle.
I tried to create an array for it and implement it to the rectangles but I can't seem to do it.

Here is the code, any help is appreciated :)

```
function setup() {
      createCanvas(500, 110);
    }
    function draw() {
  background(0, 100, 180);
  stroke(2);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    fill(0,255, 100);
    rect((i+1)*80, 50, 50, 50, 15);
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically define a color (including `alpha` attribute) using the [color()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/color) function.

Here is a working example: https://editor.p5js.org/chen-ni/sketches/aWnKXEYh1

```
var alphaValues = [50, 100, 150, 200, 250];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 110);
}

function draw() {
  background(0, 100, 180);
  stroke(2);
  rectMode(CENTER);

  for (var i = 0; i < alphaValues.length; i++) {
    var _alpha = alphaValues[i];
    var _color = color(0, 255, 100, _alpha);
    fill(_color);
    rect((i + 1) * 80, 50, 50, 50, 15);
  }
}
```